# How to see the full details of particular member when it is clicked after search?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, hybrid-mobile-app, mobile-development

I have build a search engine and I am able to fetch data successfully the only thing I want to do is whenever that searched field is selected, it will show the details. (There are further details are also present like age,house_no etc.) It is like another screen have to come with full details.

I am stuck here, please help me out. It is like navigation to another screen with full details for now I am using alert command to show the some details I want another screen please. Thanks.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  FlatList,
  TextInput,
} from 'react-native';
import { db } from '../firebase';

const App = () => {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
  const [filteredDataSource, setFilteredDataSource] = useState([]);
  const [masterDataSource, setMasterDataSource] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
        const data = await db
            .collection('Data')
            .get();
            setFilteredDataSource(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
            setMasterDataSource(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
    };
    fetchData();
}, []);

  const searchFilterFunction = (text) => {

    if (text) {
      const newData = masterDataSource.filter(
        function (item) {
          const itemData = item.FM_NAME_EN + item.EPIC_NO + item.MOBILE_NO
            ? item.FM_NAME_EN.toUpperCase() + item.EPIC_NO.toUpperCase() + item.MOBILE_NO
            : ''.toUpperCase();
          const textData = text.toUpperCase();
          return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1;
      });
      setFilteredDataSource(newData);
      setSearch(text);
    } else {
      setFilteredDataSource(masterDataSource);
      setSearch(text);
    }
  };

  const ItemView = ({item}) => {
    return (
      <Text
        style={styles.itemStyle}
        onPress={() => getItem(item)}>
        {item.FM_NAME_EN}
        {'\n'}
        {item.GENDER.toUpperCase()}
      </Text>
    );
  };

  const ItemSeparatorView = () => {
    return (
      // Flat List Item Separator
      <View
        style={{
          height: 0.5,
          width: '100%',
          backgroundColor: '#C8C8C8',
        }}
      />
    );
  };

  const getItem = (item) => {
    alert('Name : ' + item.FM_NAME_EN + ' Epic_no : ' + item.EPIC_NO);
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.textInputStyle}
          onChangeText={(text) => searchFilterFunction(text)}
          value={search}
          underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
          placeholder="Search Here"
        />
        <FlatList
          data={filteredDataSource}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={ItemSeparatorView}
          renderItem={ItemView}
        />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  itemStyle: {
    padding: 10,
  },
  textInputStyle: {
    height: 40,
    borderWidth: 1,
    paddingLeft: 20,
    margin: 5,
    borderColor: '#009688',
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
  },
});

export default App;
```

Comment: Hello, can you please share _minimal_ reproducible example. It is not clear what is the issue. You say you can `window.alert` the correct result, but I can't see any `window.alert` in your code.

Comment: @SinanYaman its not window.alert i am building a mobile application brother i have use only 'alert' option to see the full detail in alert box and its showing also which is there at getItem. as you can see in getItem. instead of alert i want to see that data in another screen. Thanks for responding to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, you have to create ItemDetails.js as the new component for the new screen:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';

const ItemDetails= () => {
  return (
    <View>
    <Text>ItemDetails screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default ItemDetails;
```

then, make sure to install react native navigation and go to create a new screen:

```
 <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
      }}>
      <Stack.Screen name="ItemDetails" component={ItemDetails} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
```

then get back to the app component and modify your getItem function to this:

```
   const getItem  = item => {
    navigation.navigate('ItemDetails', {item});
  };
```

this is how you tell the application that it has to move to another screen, and you sent the specific item with it, now let's modify our ItemDetails.js to see the data:

```
const ItemDetails = ({route}) => {
//console.log(route.params) so you can know how to access whatever you want to print
  return (
    <View>
            <Text>{route.params.item.item.FM_NAME_EN}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: @bazadough thank you for solving this brother i really appreciate it. thanks again.

Comment: that is working the details are route to another screen but as you can see my whole data in setFilteredDataSource usestate hook i want that hook on that routed screen which you have shown can i do that ????

Comment: Edit this:

const getItem  = item => {
    navigation.navigate('ItemDetails', {item, filteredDataSource});
  };
and this:
const ItemDetails = ({route, filteredDataSource}) => {
//console.log(route.params) so you can know how to access whatever you want to print
//console.log(filteredDataSource) to check if you got it in this component
  return (
    <View>
            <Text>{route.params.item.item.FM_NAME_EN}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

Comment: thankyou for your response but i still have an issue please have a look
const ItemDetails = ({ route, filteredDataSource }) => {
    const [values, setValue] = useState("")
    // console.log(route.params.filteredDataSource)

    const updateValue = () => {
        db.collection("Data")
            .doc(filteredDataSource.id)
            .update({...filteredDataSource,
                MOBILE_NO: values
            })
            .then(function () {
                alert("Mobile Number Updated Successfully")
            })
    }

Comment: filteredDataSource is not getting clone i want to update it in doc( ) as you can see

Comment: can you please be more specific?

Comment: as you told that filteredDataSource is working fine it showing all the data in console also thankyou so much for sharing that but the thing what i am doing is updating a text field i.e: MOBILE_No in the firestore database to update that it required a doc id that id i am not getting it anywhere may be i am not able to execute the logic

Comment: i tried by cloning also by giving ...(three dots) to filteredDataSource but still errors are coming that ERROR: to update doc id is missing.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you need another route:

First, create a component for the new page that will display the details:

*ItemDetails.js*:

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom' //You will get the params from the url
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'

export const ItemDetails = props => {
  const { id } = useParams()
  
  const [item, setItem] = useState(null)
  useEffect(() => {
    if(id){
      const itemSelected = /* get your item by id */
      setItem(itemSelected)
    }
  }, [id])

  return(
   <p> {item.name} </p>
   )
}
```

*Wherever you define your routes:*

```
import {ItemDetails} from './path/to/ItemDetails/'

<Switch>
   ...
   <Route exact path="/item/:id" component={ItemDetails} />
   ...
<Switch>
```

Lastly, wrap your jsx with react-router link:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

...
return (
   <Link to={`/item/${item.id}`}>
      <Text
        style={styles.itemStyle}
        {item.FM_NAME_EN}
        {'\n'}
        {item.GENDER.toUpperCase()}
      </Text>
    </Link>
    );
```

Comment: thanks for your response i appreciate it but brother i am building the app for react native you have send a code for React.js which is bit confusing for me. thanks for responding i want the solution for react native.